# Trying to swap image url's for a blurred up look but getting flickering

Tags: jquery, css, background-image, transition, blur

http://electricagenda.com/articles/public-panic-by-steph-copeland

Hey, the above link is an example.

I have a div with an inline background-image which is 50px wide, and its set to cover and center center. I also have a transition: all 200ms ease-in-out on this to smooth out the fade.

Essentially I want that to load super fast and blurred out, which it does, then swap in the larger image.

Sometimes it works perfect, sometimes on initial page load it's super quirky, upon refresh its fine.

Basically my function just swaps the large image url from the data-image to the img tag after 300ms. It also removes the original background image.

```
function loadBackground() {
  var $article_img_bg   = $('#imgFocus .bg-img'),
  $article_img_url  = $article_img_bg.data('bg');

  $article_img_bg.removeAttr('style').css('background','url(' + $article_img_url + '.jpg)' );
    }
setTimeout(loadBackground, 300);
```

Any idea's on how to improve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is a plugin that can help you - http://luis-almeida.github.io/unveil/

Comment: Thanks @ZivWeissman, ill check that out.